# Vim on Windows: characters with tilde can't be typed

Tags: vim, keyboard, terminal

I'm running vim on Windows and I'm using an US keyboard layout with deadkeys. When pressing <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, I get `a` as output (instead of `ã`).

Other info:

- <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> produces the desired `ã` on gVim.
- <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> produces the desired `ã` on Windows command prompt (outside of vim)
- <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> is, in fact, producing an `a` on vim; it's not just a matter of displaying it the wrong way. For instance  if I `:imap a b` I get a `b` when pressing either <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>.
- Other accents produced with deadkeys work as `á`, `à`, etc.
- `ã` or `õ` don't even show up when typing `dig`:

```
   A` A  192  A^ A  194  A~ A
   I" I  207  N~ Ñ  209  O` O
   a^ â  226  a~ a  227  a" ä
   o` ò  242  o^ ô  244  o~ o
```

- When copying `ã` and pasting into vim, I also get an `a`. If I save the file and open with other editor, vim actually writed an `ã`.

Comment: In `vim` to enter special characters, I have to type <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> and then type the special sequence (i.e. `~+n` or `:+o`).  Then it is inserted, though I don't use an international keyboard.

Comment: Yes, ã could also be inputed by pressing Ctrl+K, a, ~ but that also produces a `a`. I updated the question with (part of) my output to :dig (which shows vim's digraphs)

Comment: What's the `encoding` in vim? Is it using an 8-bit character set instead of utf8? Are there any other characters that look wrong in the digraph list?

Comment: I get: `fileenconding=""`, `fileencondings=utf8` and `set enconding` returns `unknown option`. There are other characters looking wrong, you can see some of them of my dig output like: `Ã`, `Ò`, `õ`, `Â`,`À`, but somewhat strangely `â`, `ô`, `á`, `ó`, `ç` look ok

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found consists on using mintty (the mintty version of vim can be installed using mingw-get.exe). As a plus you get a resizable terminal with more confortable copy-and-paste, fullscreen, etc, etc.

Comment: Is this all on your local windows machine?  or are you ssh'ing into another machine?   ssh can grab the tilde if configured to use it as an escape character.   The only other thing that comes to mind concerns your plugins.  Very odd that the mintty version works though. What terminal were you using?